Solution of coupled trigonometric equations
I am trying to solve these equations, where $k$ is a real-valued parameter:
\begin{align}
    &\cos{x} + k(\sin {x} - \sin(x+y) - 2\sin y ) - \cos( x+y) = 0, \nonumber\\
    &\cos{y} + k(2\sin x + \sin (x+y) - \sin{y} ) - \cos (x+y) = 0, \nonumber
\end{align}
Wolframalpha indicates that the solutions are
$(0, 0)$, $(\tfrac{2\pi}{3}, \tfrac{2\pi}{3})$, $(-\tfrac{2\pi}{3}, -\tfrac{2\pi}{3})$, $(0, 2tan^{-1}(3k))$,  $(-2tan^{-1}(3k), 0)$, and  $(2tan^{-1}(3k), -2tan^{-1}(3k))$.
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=cos%28x%29-cos%28x%2By%29%2Bc*%28-sin%28x%2By%29%2Bsin%28x%29-2sin%28y%29%29%3D0%2C+cos%28y%29-cos%28x%2By%29-c*%28-sin%28x%2By%29-2sin%28x%29%2Bsin%28y%29%29%3D0
Numerical simulation indicates that for all values of k, the values listed above are the exhaustive list of solutions. Is there any way to prove these are the exhaustive list of solutions?
Also, is there a method to see the steps Mathematica took to solve the above expression? WalkD[] doesn't seem to help.

Perhaps adding and subtracting the equations might give you a simpler system. From there it should be much easier to solve

I tried that, but unfortunately, it didn't produce any simpler form due to the sign difference between the sin(x+y) and cos(x+y) terms; they don't entirely cancel out by adding/subtracting the two equations.

Using the tangent half-angle substitutions
$u=\tan\frac12x$ and $v=\tan\frac12y$, we have $$\sin x=\frac{2u}{1+u^2}\quad \cos x=\frac{1-u^2}{1+u^2}\quad \sin y=\frac{2v}{1+v^2}\quad \cos y=\frac{1-v^2}{1+v^2}$$ and the equations become
$$\begin{align}
v (u^2 v + k u^2 - 2 k u v - 2 u - v + 3 k ) &=0 \tag1 \\
u (u v^2 - k v^2 + 2 k u v - u - 2 v - 3 k ) &=0 \tag2
\end{align}$$

If $u=0$ (which satisfies $(2)$), equation $(1)$ becomes
$$v(v-3k)=0 \tag3$$
giving solutions $(u,v)=(0,0)$ and $(0,3k)$, corresponding to $(x,y)=(0,0)$ and $(0,2\tan^{-1}(3k))$.
If $v=0$ (which satisfies $(1)$), equation $(2)$ becomes
$$u(u+3k) =0 \tag4$$ giving additional solution $(x,y)=(-2\tan^{-1}(3k),0)$.
Otherwise, we can concentrate on the long factors in $(1)$ and $(2)$. Solving the second for $v$ and substituting into the first gives
$$v = \frac{3 k - 2 u + k u^2}{1 + 2 k u - u^2}  \qquad\qquad
 (u-3k) (u^2-3)\cdot (u^2+1)(k^2+1)=0 \tag5$$ For real $u$ and $k$, we can ignore the last two factors, leaving $u=3k$ and $u=\pm\sqrt{3}$, which give $v=-3k$ and $v=\pm\sqrt{3}$, corresponding to solutions $(x,y)=(2\tan^{-1}(3k),-2\tan^{-1}(3k))$, and $\pm(2\pi/3,2\pi/3)$.

This accounts for all the solutions provided by WolframAlpha, and indicates that there are no more.

Thanks a lot!!!
